# Query to mass delete members in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, spam

I had a lot of spam members in my WordPress installation (thanks to BuddyPress and it's horrible system of registration and profile syncing). I would like to run a query to delete all members who have registered in last one month (or any particular time frame).

Then, how to delete the corresponding records from `wp_usermeta` table too along with deleting records from `wp_users` table?

Comment: Edited answer on how to clean up meta completely from non-existent users.

Comment: Here's another answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-can-i-delete-all-users-which-have-never-commented-have-posted-spam-comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), user_registered) < 30; -- 30 is the time in days
```

I would recommend, as with any destructive query, first testing it by replacing `DELETE` with `SELECT *`.

Afterwards clean up meta with:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `wp_users`);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. However, as mentioned I've a Buddypress thing too, the member count of WordPress core and buddypress isn't tallying up! Can you suggest a solution for that.?

Comment: Never even heard of Buddypress, so out of luck there.